# Correlation Coefficient between $x$ and $y$ and between $x$ and $\begin{Bmatrix} y+x \end{Bmatrix}$

Tags: correlation

> Let  Let Correlation Coefficient between $x$ and $y$  be $R$ and between
>   $x$ and $\begin{Bmatrix} y+x \end{Bmatrix}$ be $S$ , then
>
> a) $R<S$
>
> b) $R>S$
>
> c)$R=S$
>
> d) None of the above

The correct answer is none of the above, can anyone explain why? , then

Comment: Since this looks like a self-study question I just give a hint: variances.

Comment: As @ahstat argument shows below, a correct statement would be that if the correlation coefficient exists, then $\operatorname{Corr}(X, Y) \leq \operatorname{Corr}(X, X + Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you take $x = (1,2,3)$ and $y = (4,5,6)$, there are linearly dependent and you can see that $R=S=1$ (then a/ and b/ cannot be true).

If you take $x = (1,2,3)$ and $y = (-2,-4,-3)$, then $0.5 = S \geq R = 1$ (then c/ cannot be true).

Generally, we have $R \leq S$ (assuming the correlation exists).

You need to use the triangular inequality for the standard deviation:
$\sigma_{X+Y} \leq \sigma_{X} + \sigma_{Y}.$

Then, you can write: 
$$R = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}},$$ whereas:
$$S = \frac{Cov(X,X+Y)}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{X+Y}}$$

For $S$, using bilinearity of $Cov$,
$$S = \frac{\sigma_{X}^2 + Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{X+Y}}.$$
Using the triangular inequality:
$$S \geq \frac{\sigma_{X}^2 + Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_{X}(\sigma_{X}+\sigma_{Y})} = \frac{\sigma_{X}^2 + Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_{X}^2+\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}}.$$

You can then compare $A:= \frac{\sigma_{X}^2 + Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_{X}^2+\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}}$ with $R$ and conclude that $R \leq S$.

Comment: Almost a complete argument? To show $\frac{\sigma^2_X + Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma^2_X + \sigma_X\sigma_Y} \geq \frac{ Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}$ one can use [Cauchy Schwartz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) to show $\sigma_x \sigma_y \geq Cov(X,Y)$. Then $\sigma^3_X \sigma_Y + \sigma_X \sigma_Y Cov(X,Y) \geq \sigma^2_X Cov(X,Y) + \sigma_X \sigma_Y Cov(X,Y)$ and $\sigma_X \sigma_Y \left( \sigma^2_X +  Cov(X,Y) \right) \geq \left( \sigma^2_X  + \sigma_X \sigma_Y \right) Cov(X,Y)$

Comment: yes, we need this inequality to conclude

Answer (score 1):

Here are the examples of random variables $X$ and $Y$ to demonstrate that none of the first three options holds.

1. When $Y = -X$, then correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is $R = -1$ and between $X$ and $X+Y = 0$ is $S = 0$. This rules out options (b) and (c).
2. When $Y = X$, then correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is $R = 1$ and between $X$ and $X+Y = 2X$ is also $S = 1$. This rules out options (a) and (b).